# what should i use for google signin: https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs OR https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client?

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm building a SPA in javascript that is going to work as webapp as well as cordova/crosswalk hybrid app. I need a signin strategy to verify user identity on my nodejs server, I DON'T need any google cloud service just an identity verification as there'll be no other login/registration possibility for that SPA.
I'm not able to find the right combination of tools/library/protocols...to secure the signin proccess. 
I'm going to use this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in
for browser/mobileapp side singin but I don't know what to do server side as there are at least 2 library from google:
https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs
 https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client
plus the famous passportjs npm module, I've been reading a lot of articles  in the last few days but I've not found a best practice.
Some one knows which one is the right and most stable library/tool to use server-side? (nodejs) 
thanks in advance

Comment: I work at Google, thanks for point this out. google-api-nodejs-client actually uses google-auth-library-nodejs and both are maintained and supported libraries. Sounds like you just need the authentication functionality, so you should be fine to go with google-auth-library-nodejs and take the lighter-weight dependency.

Comment: Or you can use any Json Web Token validation library, such as passportjs, but make sure to do the critical security checks described in the documentation (issuer/signature, audience and expiration validation): https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token ... let me know if these answer your question.

Comment: Hi, yes these answers my question. I'm going to use just google-auth-library-nodejs. Thanks